# How to put the two regions and countries data on OpenStreetMap into postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, nominatim

I'm developing a WebGIS in Linux development platform that cannot use internet and need to deal with maps and positioning.

I have used nominatim on OpenStreetMap to implement it. I use postgresql and postgis as my database according to the installation steps of OSM website. Now I have established the server, which contain one country data. I use the following statement to import the first country data:

```
su test
download/Nominatim-2.5.1/utils/setup.php --osm-file download/country-latest.osm.pbf --all
```

I try to use the following statement to import the second country data:

```
su test
download/Nominatim-2.5.1/utils/setup.php --osm-file download/anothercountry-latest.osm.pbf --all
```

It shows "the nominatim database already exists".

```
su test
download/Nominatim-2.5.1/utils/setup.php --osm-file download/country-latest.osm.pbf anothercountry-latest.osm.pbf --all
```

It shows "The file or directory could not be found".

So how do I import the second country data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would probably be cleaner to join the two PBF files before you do the load. Something like

```
osmosis --read-pbf file="countryA.pbf" --read-pbf file="countryB.pbf"  --merge --write-pbf file="merged.pbf"
```

then just use `merged.pbf` for the load.

If you have more than that, you can just keep adding them, but you need a `--merge` for each one (so three countries needs two `--merge` commands, just after each other).

Comment: I have used the `osmosis --read-xml file="countryA.pbf" --read-xml file="countryB.pbf" --write-xml file="merged.pbf"` statement, but it shows "Execution aborted.
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: The following named pipes () and 1 default pipes have not been terminated with appropriate output sinks."

Comment: Updated it to add the missing command, and to use the right kind of read and write commands (pbf vs xml). Sorry.

Comment: I'm sorry for bother you again. I have done as the updated command, however, it shows "Task type read-pbf doesn't exist."

Comment: What version of osmosis do you have?

Comment: 0.44.1-4 it shows "It is the latest version."

Comment: Do you have osmosis-pbf.jar plugin (probably in /usr/share/osmosis/osmosis-pbf.jar if you installed from packages on Ubuntu)? What about /usr/share/java/protobuf.jar or something similar? Are you using some locked-down system like SELinux?

Comment: I have osmosis-pbf-0.44.1-4.jar plugin in /usr/share/osmosis/osmosis-pbf.jar. I think I am not using locked-down system, because I only installed nominatim after installing the system. I just tried to execute  pbf command again, and  two country data was synthesized successfully. I think this error is because I entered the internal database. Thanks.

Comment: So you are all OK now?

Comment: Yes, now I am importing the merged data to postgresql. Thank you very much.